# RandomForestSRC error and vimp

Tags: random-forest, survival-analysis

I am trying to perform a randomforest survival analysis according to the RANDOMFORESTSRC vignette in R. I have a data frame containing 59 variables - where 14 of them are numeric and the rest are factors. 2 of the numeric ones are TIME (days till death) and DIED (0/1 dead or not). I'm running into 2 problems:

```
trainrfsrc<- rfsrc(Surv(TIME, DIED) ~ .,
                   data = train, nsplit = 10, na.action = "na.impute")
```

trainrfsrc gives: Error rate: 17.07%

works fine, however exploring the error rate such as:

```
plot(gg_error(trainrfsrc))+ coord_cartesian(y = c(.09,.31))
```

returns:

```
geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
```

or:

```
a<-(gg_error(trainrfsrc))

a 
error ntree 1 NA 1 2 NA 2 3 NA 3 4 NA 4 5 NA 5 6 NA 6 7 NA 7 8 NA 8 9 NA 9 10 NA 10
```

NA for all 1000 trees.how come there's no error rate for each number of trees tried?

the second problem is when trying to explore the most important variables using VIMP such as:

```
plot(gg_vimp(trainrfsrc)) + theme(legend.position = c(.8,.2))+ labs(fill = "VIMP > 0")
```

it returns:

```
In gg_vimp.rfsrc(trainrfsrc) : rfsrc object does not contain VIMP information. Calculating...
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Setting the err.block=1 (or some integer between 1 and ntree) should fix the problem of returning NA for error. You can check the help file under rfsrc to read more about err.block.